# Extjs 4 grid customization after clicking on a row add a panel with a textfield

Tags: extjs4.1

I am new to extjs 4 and I have got a problem to customize the grid panel. My application have JSON data to render in a grid. After populate the data when user click on a particular row he need to get an panel (Just like row editing plugin) of a textfield and a button to send the entered text to server through the controller. This data that user entered is not the data of grid column.

I need to know is it possible? And if it is, then how can I make it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible. First look at the following [example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/form-grid.html) from the Extjs 4.1 docs

All you need is to add your listener to [**itemclick**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-itemclick) grid event. Within this listener function you can create panel you need.